# How to do a findOneAndUpdate with bluebird promises (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bluebird

I cannot find any examples on how to resolve promises with bluebird when using mongoose's findOneAndUpdate.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var mongoose = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));

//actions is an array of objects with queries and upsert data

var promises = actions.map(function(arr) {
    return MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(arr.query, arr.upsertData, {'upsert': true}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
            //return err;
        } else {
            console.log('doc: ', doc);
            //return Promise.resolve();
        }
    });
});
//once all db transactions are finished:
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function() {

        console.log('all done');

        //this is where I want to output all the documents once they are updated or added

    })
    .error(function(err) {
        console.log('error:', err);
    });
```

So far, I've looked at bluebird and also async. I need to pass different options to the query, which I could not get to work with either library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mongoose's `Query` class, an instance of which [`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) returns, has an [`.exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) method that returns a promise:

```
var promises = actions.map(function(arr) {
  return MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(arr.query, arr.upsertData, {'upsert': true}).exec();
});
```

You get the results in an array:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) { ... });
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, but that is not working for me. I get an error: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined and below is my code. 
`module.exports.updateUser = function (uuid, data) {
    return User.findOneAndUpdate({uuid:uuid},data,function (err, user){
        if (err) return err;
        
        return true;
    }).exec();
};`
Do you see anything weird?

Comment: @Shaidar don't pass a callback function if you want to use promises.

Comment: Hi @robertklep can you do ```var promises = actions.map(function(arr) {
  return MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(arr.query, arr.upsertData, {'upsert': true}).exec().then(...).catch(...);
});```

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett yes, should be possible, `.catch()` itself also returns a promise.

Comment: @robertklep it works just wanted know if the implementation is correct

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett looks fine to me :D

Comment: @robertklep kool